# Modifying Django ModelForm.cleaned_data has no effect on saved Model

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model where one boolean ModelField is dependent upon another. The Model is configured like so:

```
class Situation(models.Model):
    ctcs = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Cross-Technology Critical Situation", blank=True)
    has_been_ctcs = models.BooleanField(editable=False, default=False)
```

The `ctcs` field is rendered as a checkbox in the ModelForm for this model. What I want to do is, if the `ctcs` field has been checked, I also want to set `has_been_ctcs` to True. So what I am doing is setting `cleaned_data['has_been_ctcs'] = True` on the ModelForm. I've tried doing this both in my view that handles the POST request, as well as within the ModelForm `clean` function like so:

```
class SituationForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(SituationForm, self).clean()
       ctcs = cleaned_data.get("ctcs")
       if ctcs:
           self.cleaned_data['has_been_ctcs'] = True
       return cleaned_data
```

And here is the snippet from the view that handles creation of a new `Situation` model:

```
sit_form = SituationForm(request.POST)
if sit_form.is_valid():
    print sit_form.cleaned_data['ctcs']  # Prints True
    if sit_form.cleaned_data['ctcs']:
        print "Checking form has_been_ctcs"
        # Have also tried setting sit_form.cleaned_data['has_been_ctcs'] here, no difference from doing it in `def clean()`
        print sit_form.cleaned_data['has_been_ctcs']  # Prints True
    sit = sit_form.save()
    print sit.has_been_ctcs  # Prints False
```

I cannot seem to get the `has_been_ctcs` value of True to propagate to the `Situation` model. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cleaned_data` only works for fields that are included in the form. What you want to do is:

```
sit_form = SituationForm(request.POST)
if sit_form.is_valid():
    if sit_form.cleand_data['ctcs']:
        sit_form.instance.has_been_ctcs = True
    sit = sit_form.save()
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. I kept it in the `def clean()` method so it works for both my create and update views without repeating code. Appreciate the help! Will mark as correct answer as soon as SO lets me.